# How can I factor a set of systemProperty calls out of a set of Gradle java tasks?

Tags: java, gradle, task

I need to set the same list of system properties for various tasks in my build file, e.g.:

```
test {
  systemProperty 'foo', 'bar'
  systemProperty 'key', 'value'
}
run {
  systemProperty 'foo', 'bar'
  systemProperty 'key', 'value'
}
task(dbg, dependsOn: 'classes', type: JavaExec) {
  systemProperty 'foo', 'bar'
  systemProperty 'key', 'value'
}
```

What's the right way to refactor these into a helper? I tried an ext.myMethod but it doesn't know about the systemProperty call (nor jvmArgs, environment, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me propose to just put the system properties into a map and reuse this map in multiple calls to the [`systemProperties`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/process/JavaForkOptions.html#systemProperties-java.util.Map-) method of the selected tasks:

```
def myProperties = [
    foo: 'bar',
    key: 'value'
]

test {
    systemProperties myProperties
}

run {
    systemProperties myProperties
}

// ...
```